# Elaborating an example that shows that pointwise convergence is not sufficient to pass the limit under the integral sign.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, pointwise-convergence

The example is given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- I do not understand the definition of $f_{n}$, could anyone explain it for me, please?

2- How is $\int_{0}^{1} f_{n} = 1$?

3- What is the intuition behind this definition of $f_{n}$?

Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: (1) Look at [its graph](https://images.app.goo.gl/poWatWV58n7YVccm8) (2) Look at (1). (3) Keeping the same area under the curve, while bringing, eventually, the values to zero, at every point.

Comment: For 1) and 2), have you tried to sketch the graph of $f_n$? The idea is that for large $n$, you get a triangle with large height and very small base length, so it cancels out into a constant area.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I can see many graphs in the link you provided, which one exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Mindlack no I have not, I am not understanding the definition.

Comment: The general graph is the one leftmost, representing “$f_k$”. The graphs on the right show how $f_k$ evolves for $k=1,2,\ldots,5$.

Comment: And why specifically when $x \geq 2/n$ @Mindlack

Comment: What about the graphs below those graphs?@Mindlack

Comment: $2/n$ is the point where the decreasing linear part hits zero again. Also, don’t mind the graphs below.

Comment: Your assistance for me was quite helpful. thank u! :) @Mindlack

Comment: @Smart the top graph(s) are the functions $f_k$. They use $k$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Thank u so much :) @conditionalMethod

Comment: I would have used a very similar but simpler example: $$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n & \text{if } 0<x<1/n, \\ 0 & \text{if } x\ge 1/n \text{ or } x\le 0. \end{cases} $$ Then you have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\,dx = 1 \quad \ne \quad 0 = \int\limits_{\mathbb R} \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\,dx.
$$

Comment: @Mindlack I think also there is a typo in the example and it should be $f_{n} (1/n) = n$ and also $f_{n}(0) = 0$ not just $f (1/n) = n$ and not just $f(0) = 0$  ..... am I correct?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think also there is a typo in the example and it should be $f_{n} (1/n) = n$ and also $f_{n}(0) = 0$ not just $f (1/n) = n$ and not just $f(0) = 0$  ..... am I correct?

Comment: @MichaelHardy how is your second integral =0 ?

Comment: @Smart: because $\lim_{n}f_n(x)=f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The book has typos as you mentioned: "$f(1/n)=n$ and $f(0)=0$..." should really be
   $$
   f_n(1/n)=n, \quad f_n(0)=0.
   $$

   (The authors only say later that "Define $f\equiv 0$ on $[0,1]$".)

   The graph of the function $f_k$ is as follows:

   > [image]
2. $\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx=1$ follows from the graph above: just consider the area of the triangle.
3. This is one of the example showing that "pointwise convergence alone is not sufficient to justify passage of the limit under the integral sign". This is one type of "escape to infinity".

   If one does not require continuity, a common used example is $f_n=n1_{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]}$.

Comment: but this drawing does not show that $f_{1}(1) = 1.$

Comment: @Smart: this drawing does not show $f_6, f_7,\cdots$ either. The first picture shows the general case. And of course when $k=1$, $\frac{1}{k}=1$ and $\frac{2}{k}=2$.

Comment: what do you mean by "escape to infinity"?

Comment: why we require continuity here?

Comment: @Smart For "escape to infinity", see this set of lecture notes: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/

Comment: I can not understand the meaning of the 1 given in the example in your last line .... could you clarify its meaning  please?

Comment: I do not say we "require" continuity. All I said is that this example has the property that the sequence of functions are all continuous.

Comment: That's the indicator function. $1_{A}$ is the same as $\chi_A$ in Royden where $A$ is a set.

Comment: You are amazing Jack .... thank you soooo much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$1).\ $ For each integer $n$, draw the graph of $f_n$. They will be triangles of decreasing base and increasing height.

$2).\ $ Although the dimensions of the triangles are changing, the area is not.

$3).\ $ For each $x\in [0,1]$, all the $f_n's$ are eventually zero at $x$ so $\underset{n\to\infty}\lim f_n(x)=0$ but the areas are steady at a value $1$ so.....

Comment: What do u mean by the areas of the areas?

Comment: it's a typo sorry. I will fix it, thanks

Comment: I think also there is a typo in the example and it should be $f_{n} (1/n) = n$ and also $f_{n}(0) = 0$ not just $f (1/n) = n$ and not just $f(0) = 0$  ..... am I correct?

Comment: thank you so much for your very precise explanation

Comment: You are welcome